# C# Discord.net Bot disconnects after joining a voice channel

Tags: c#, discord.net

I wrote a discord bot, and i want it to join a voice channel after an user joins it, but what it does, is join it, wait a second and then disconnect with the following errors poping up in the console:

```
System.TimeoutException: The operation has timed out.
   at Discord.WebSocket.SocketGuild.ConnectAudioAsync(UInt64 channelId, Boolean selfDeaf, Boolean selfMute, Boolean external)
   at Discord.WebSocket.SocketGuild.ConnectAudioAsync(UInt64 channelId, Boolean selfDeaf, Boolean selfMute, Boolean external)
   at Discord.WebSocket.SocketVoiceChannel.ConnectAsync(Boolean selfDeaf, Boolean selfMute, Boolean external)
   at DiscordBot2.Program.ConnectToVoice(SocketVoiceChannel voiceChannel)
   at DiscordBot2.Program.OnVoiceStateUpdated(SocketUser user, SocketVoiceState state1, SocketVoiceState state2)
```

Here is the code i utilised:

```C#
// called before calling StartAsync
_client.UserVoiceStateUpdated += OnVoiceStateUpdated;

private async Task OnVoiceStateUpdated(SocketUser user, SocketVoiceState state1, SocketVoiceState state2)
        {
            // Check if this was a non-bot user joining a voice channel
            if (user.IsBot)
                return;

            if (state1.VoiceChannel == null && state2.VoiceChannel != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    await ConnectToVoice(state2.VoiceChannel);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                }
            }
        }

        private async Task ConnectToVoice(SocketVoiceChannel voiceChannel)
        {
            if (voiceChannel == null)
                return;

            Console.WriteLine($"Connecting to channel {voiceChannel.Id}");
            var connection = await voiceChannel.ConnectAsync();
            Console.WriteLine($"Connected to channel {voiceChannel.Id}");
        }
```